# Java web application event

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets

I am writing a code for a web application using Java and Apache Tomcat. The web application involves an authentication system. My question: is there any way that I can execute a certain code every time my web application receives a request. So instead of adding the code to check if the user is logged in every page, the code gets called automatically when the application receives a request.
Thanks!

Comment: look at apache tomcat valves or filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you should take a look on HTTP Filter.

You should implement interface `javax.servlet.Filter`, register you filter in `web.xml` using `<filter>` tag and your filter will be called on each call of URL you mapped to this filter.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least a couple of options

- make all your servlets extend the same base class and put the shared code in the `service` method
- use a J2EE filter to intercept the message and put the shared code there

I'd go for the second of these options, providing that it's not too much of a code restructure. Authentication is a cross-cutting concern and is exactly what the Filter framework was designed to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You could use filter to control the event call.

You also can use tomcat container's background thread follow the event every 5 min.

Answer (score 0):

Form-based authentication is for you.